# Ussing setTimeout inside a loop to not allow blocking

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, settimeout

Some lines of code to give you the idea what I'm trying to ask.
Code starts with

```
var webSocketsServerPort = 8002;
var webSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var conns = [];
```

I use the array conns to push the users after each successful connection. I put there additional (their ID) information so I can identify the user.

And when I need to send a specific information to a user I call the following function.

```
function sendMessage(userID, message){
    for(var i = 0, len = conns.length; i < len; ++i){
        if(conns[i].customData.ID == userID){
            conns[i].sendUTF(message);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is:
Is it a better idea if replace `conns[i].sendUTF(message);` with `setTimeout(function(){conns[i].sendUTF(message)},1)` so that in case there are 5000 connected users `sendUTF(msg)` will not be able to block the loop and in the best case all the messages will be sent at the same time.

Comment: *First:* break out of the loop when you find the id! *Second:* Why use a loop? The change the design so you do not need a loop!

Comment: How can I change the design?

Comment: Object with the user id as a key.

Comment: And then how to make a list of the users with the same username.

Comment: How does that apply? You are saying multiple people can have the same ID?

Comment: In case the same user has multiple tabs open or is using the app on his smartphone at the same time.

Comment: so than the id would hold multiple connections.

Comment: Multiple objects (connections) with the same `ID`. And when I want to send some data to a specific user I run a for loop through it to detect all connections from that user. I don't like this idea but do I have another choice?

Comment: So basically you have a keychain with 500 keys on it and 3 work the same door. You can either label the keys and just pick them out or you need to try every key and see if it fits. You loop or you don't

Comment: Please tell me a simple solution without using loops.

Comment: But how do I select them later if I use object with the user id as a key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63231/discussion-between-enve-and-epascarello).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your design to order everything by an id instead of an Array of objects, there is no reason to have to loop to find all of the user's connection. You would only need to loop through the multiple connections for each user.

```
var connections = {};
function addConnection (userId, conn) { 
    if (!connections[userId]) {
        connections[userId] = [];
    }
    connections[userId].push(conn);
}

var getUserConnections (userId) {
    return connections[userId];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That wouldn't help in the way you are thinking. If it's not going to "block" at that time, it will "block" in 1 ms.

Answer (score 1):

Doing `setTimeout` that way will only delay the execution, but not the queueing. JS will still blockingly run your `for` loop to get all 5000 items into the waiting queue before clearing the stack for the other things.

What you need is to give way each iteration. Since you're on NodeJS, you can use `process.nextTick()` to schedule the next iteration. Here's a quick example.

```
var i = 0;
var length = cons.length;

function foo(){
  // if not yet the limit, schedule the next
  if(i++ < length) process.nextTick(foo);

  // Run as usual
  if(conns[i].customData.ID == userID) conns[i].sendUTF(message);

}
```